# consume Activemq message from jmeter

Tags: jmeter

```html
<SubscriberSampler guiclass="JMSSubscriberGui" testclass="SubscriberSampler" testname="JMS Subscriber" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="jms.jndi_properties">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="jms.initial_context_factory">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="jms.provider_url">tcp://127.0.0.1:61610</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="jms.connection_factory">ConnectionFactory</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="jms.topic">dynamicQueue/MyQueue</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="jms.security_principle">admin</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="jms.security_credentials">admin</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="jms.authenticate">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="jms.iterations">1</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="jms.read_response">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="jms.client_choice">jms_subscriber_on_message</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="jms_error_reconnect_on_codes"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="jms.selector">type=&apos;Queue&apos;</stringProp>
        </SubscriberSampler>
```

I need consume active mq message from jmeter 
I have configured JMS Subscriber but getting errer message

Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2019-09-11 18:52:42 BST
Load time: 0
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 0
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 000
Response message: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: dynamicQueue/MyQueue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below queue name "dynamicQueues/MyQueue" instead of dynamicQueue/MyQueue

You can refer:
     https://activemq.apache.org/how-to-unit-test-jms-code

Comment: Thanks.Its working the dynamicQueues/MyQueue. Everywhere the option in the example says with topics not for the quoue. my quename not correct and working after changes

Answer (score 0):

> NameNotFoundException: dynamicQueue/MyQueue

As per [javax.naming.NameNotFoundException JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/NameNotFoundException.html)

> This exception is thrown when a component of the name cannot be resolved because it is not bound.

Double check that the queue and/or topic exists and your user has enough rights to access it. The easiest way of checking is using the [ActiveMQ Web Console](https://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html)

Check out [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter/) article for instructions on sending/receiving JMS messages using JMeter